# Typesetting predicate natural deduction rules

Tags: math-mode, logic

I have a rule for natural deduction that I'd like to typeset. It looks like this:

[image: Universal quantifier introduction]

How should I go about typesetting this with LaTeX? Should I use one of the packages (e.g. `logicproof`) - it seems a bit overkill given I'm not typesetting an actual proof, only one of the rules that can be used. I've also considered just using a `\frac` and maybe a `tabular` environment but this seems a bit messy.

Comment: I think it could be done using tikz: 5 text nodes for each text, 1 rectangle node, and one horizontal path underneath the rectangle

Comment: The best approach is to start at the LaTeX for Logicians site and see if something there does what you need or can be adapted to do it. That generally gets you more intuitive and shorter code than manually laying stuff out.

Comment: @Jason If `logicproof` is overkill, then surely `tikz` is :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Tiuri's nice answer, but with stacks, instead of matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{
  \,\fbox{$
  \tabbedLongstack{x_0 & \\ & \vdots \\ & \phi[x_0/x]}
  $}_{\strut}\,
}{
  \forall x\,\phi
}
\forall x\,\mathrm{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `\boxed` around a `matrix` environment (or similar) in math mode to get the box, and then to just use a `\frac`. With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\boxed{\begin{matrix}
        x_0 & \\
        & \vdots \\
        & \phi[x_0/x]
    \end{matrix}}_{\strut}}{\forall x\phi}\forall xi
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

Edit: The `\strut` from Steven's solution makes a lot of sense here, too.